# Pandas data frame group by

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with column say 'id','name','value' . I want to group the data by 'id' and con-cat the data in column 'name','value' , how can i do that. I did this

```
attributes['name'] = attributes[['product_uid','name','value']].groupby(['product_uid'])['name'].transform(lambda x:','.join(str(x)))

attributes['value'] = attributes[['product_uid','name','value']].groupby(['product_uid'])['value'].transform(lambda x:','.join(str(x)))
```

but this seems to be slow. Is there any efficient method??

Comment: What are the dtypes here? if you did `attributes.astype(str).groupby('product_id').apply(''.join)` does this work?

Comment: It can be float and also string .

Comment: Did what I suggest work?

Comment: I will try that and let know

Comment: It doesn't work @EdChum . all my rows now shows only the header strings

Comment: Giving a data sample wouldn't hurt.

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-depot-product-search-relevance/data here is the data